# Unable to sudo apt-get update and I want to install 32bit libraries

Tags: pi-4

So I've been trying to install 32 bit libraries to my 64 bit pi.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:armhf libstdc++6:armhf
```

and the result is

```
gz-01@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
gz-01@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease                 
  Connection failed [IP: 2a00:1098:82:47::2:1 80]
Fetched 48.4 kB in 23s (2,059 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 2a00:1098:82:47::2:1 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
gz-01@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install libc6:armhf libstdc++6:armhf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfuse2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-10-base:armhf krb5-locales libcom-err2:armhf libcrypt1:armhf
  libgcc-s1:armhf libgssapi-krb5-2:armhf libidn2-0:armhf libk5crypto3:armhf
  libkeyutils1:armhf libkrb5-3:armhf libkrb5support0:armhf libnsl2:armhf
  libnss-nis:armhf libnss-nisplus:armhf libssl1.1:armhf libtirpc3:armhf
  libunistring2:armhf
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:armhf locales:armhf krb5-doc:armhf krb5-user:armhf
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-10-base:armhf krb5-locales libc6:armhf libcom-err2:armhf libcrypt1:armhf
  libgcc-s1:armhf libgssapi-krb5-2:armhf libidn2-0:armhf libk5crypto3:armhf
  libkeyutils1:armhf libkrb5-3:armhf libkrb5support0:armhf libnsl2:armhf
  libnss-nis:armhf libnss-nisplus:armhf libssl1.1:armhf libstdc++6:armhf
  libtirpc3:armhf libunistring2:armhf
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,588 kB/5,766 kB of archives.
After this operation, 18.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libc6 armhf 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u5
  Connection failed [IP: 2a00:1098:80:56::1:1 80]
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main armhf libssl1.1 armhf 1.1.1n-0+deb11u3+rpt1
  Connection failed [IP: 2a00:1098:82:47::1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.31-13%2brpt2%2brpi1%2bdeb11u5_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 2a00:1098:80:56::1:1 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0%2bdeb11u3%2brpt1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 2a00:1098:82:47::1 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So does anyone has any opinions on how to resolve the [failed to fetch] and [connection failed]?

this is what I am trying to do [image]

I am trying to use the ASIC HUB on Minerstat but I need to install 32 bit libraries to be able to work properly.

Comment: It is far from clear what you are attempting to accomplish. One thing is that using apt-get is wrong. In an interactive context use apt.

Comment: asking for opinions is not allowed here, because all opinions are valid